# join two file based on column when there is no one by one corespondness in bash script (awk, grep , sed)

Tags: bash, awk

**file1.txt**

```
112|9305|/inst.exe    
112|9305|/lkj.exe    
112|9305|/dje.jar    
112|9305|/ind.pdf    
112|9306|/ma.exe    
112|9306|/ngg.pdf    
112|9307|/jhhh.dat    
112|9312|/ee.dat    
112|9312|/qwq.dll
```

**file2.txt**

```
117|9305|www.gahan.com    
117|9306|www.google.com    
117|9312|www.mihan.com    
117|9307|translate.com
```

**expected output**

```
112|9305|www.gahan.com/inst.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/lkj.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/dje.jar
112|9305|www.gahan.com/ind.pdf
112|9306|www.google.com/ma.exe
112|9306|www.google.com/ngg.pdf
112|9307|translate.com/jhhh.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/ee.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/qwq.dll
```

I want to add third column of `file2.txt` to third column of `file1.txt` based on second column values. In fact I want join them based on second column but there is **no one bye one correspondence between them**. How can I do these with awk or grep or sed in shell script.

Answer (score 1):

You can use awk like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="|"} FNR==NR{a[$2]=$3; next} $2 in a{$3=a[$2] $3} 1' file2.txt file1.txt
112|9305|www.gahan.com/inst.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/lkj.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/dje.jar
112|9305|www.gahan.com/ind.pdf
112|9306|www.google.com/ma.exe
112|9306|www.google.com/ngg.pdf
112|9307|translate.com/jhhh.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/ee.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/qwq.dll
```